# Temperature map in mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a set of data from temperature sensors in an area, 3 coordinates + a temperature value: {x, y, z, t}. The number of points is not that big, 15-20, so it can be typed directly. I need to create gradient temperature maps from it: It could be a cube similar to what Plot3D does but most important I need a set of 2d sections by different height: z = 0.5, z = 1 etc. (The coordinates are in meters.)

I tried to use ListDensityPlot3D for a cube and ListSliceDensityPlot for sections but I can't find a way to feed it with a fixed set of points all documanted examples are about Table(...) defining a function and an interval.

Any idea how to do this? I'm pretty sure it is a trivial task its just that I use Mathematica once per 2-3 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no requirement that the data will be given on a grid. It can certainly given at arbitrary locations (but of course you'll have to worry about how good your interpolation is).

Here's a `ListSliceDensityPlot3D` of 30 random data points:

```
dat = RandomReal[1, {30, 4}]
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[dat, "CenterPlanes"]
```

[image]

Comment: It helped, thanks! But do you know how to get a flat 2d section and not a cube with sections like the one ListSliceDensityPlot3D provides? I need just images of vertical sections with z = 1, 2 etc.

Comment: @ElDog just replace "CenterPlanes" by ""ZStackedPlanes"

Comment: I did it. But what I mean, I need a set of flat images to insert in a document, not a cube with sections. Cube is impressive too and an be used, but I also need images.

Comment: In that case you should probably construct an `interp=Interpolation[...your data... ]` and simply plot it at different z's with whichever function you like, say to plot at z=2 you can do `DensityPlot[interp[x, y, 2],... ]`